# On-line mapcode to GPS (or street address) converter

Tags: gps, service-recommendations

My car GPS navigation unit has a stored location and gives it as a mapcode (2 groups of 4 characters separated with a dot).  I've searched but can't find any on-line converter that can take this mapcode and at least convert it to lat/long coordinates or (more useful) a street address.  There seem to be lots of converters that can go in the other direction (give a mapcode for a street address).

Is there an on-line mapcode - to - coordinates or mapcode - to - address converter?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  The Question is unclear without specifying the navigation unit or providing more detail on the "mapcode".

Answer (score -1):

Ah, I have found this:

https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/download.mapcode.com/getcoordst.html

For a location outside the Netherlands, select "international" and include the country code before the geocode in the search box.